# Vue mdi icons inside string

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid, mdi

How can I use mdi icons inside a string and return it in a method which will act as a component of a cell in aggrid table.

```
import { mdiPencil } from "@mdi/js";
data(){
  return{
    mdiPencil
  }
}
methods:{
 viewButton() {
   return `<v-btn icon><v-icon>{{ mdiPencil }}</v-icon></v-btn>`;
 },
}
```

The above is my method. For now it displays `{{mdiPencil}}` as a string and not an icon in the aggrid table cell. How do I display the icon?

Comment: How you render this string?

Comment: Why not just use markup in your template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
return `<svg role="img" class="v-icon__svg">
        <path d="${mdiPencil}"></path>
      </svg>`;
```